# IOS - WKWebView upload file

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview

I have a problem with my iPhone app that only happens on iOS version 13.5.
I have a webview (WKWebView) that contains a photo upload form using JQuery, but when selecting the image in the Photo Library the error below occurs and for this reason, the build in the Apple Store is disapproved.

```
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x600000e2fcf0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x7ff8776120e0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this an ionic app?

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad No, is an ios native app.

Comment: @RogérioSilva have you solved this issue? i am facing same issue.

Comment: @RogérioSilva did you ever find a solution for that? we're also having the same issue and couldn't find anything about it